# Put RIA Services on a separate solutions

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I have a solution for my client( Silverlight application) and a solution for my server.

when found many tutorial on how creating a RIA service on the same solution.

But I want to put the RIA service in the server side but I don't find a tutorial that say how to do it.

Can someone give me a tutorial for that purpose ?

Answer (score 1):

If you create a project of type WCF Ria Services Class Library, you can compile it to dll and reference it in you other solution.

Answer (score 0):

No problem, you can. 
Open the .csproj project "silverlight side" and be sure to insert a tag like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
...
    <LinkedServerProject>..\MyFolder\MyDomainServerProject.csproj</LinkedServerProject>
...
```